# Publishing C# application with Wix and MS-Access

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, wix

I have created a visual studio app with an access database and connected the two using a connection string. The database is in the same folder that the solution is in.

Is this how this should be set up to allow the app to run on a different system? Or is there something else I need to do with the database when creating the installer? (assuming the other systems that it will run on WILL have access and the correct .NET framework installed).

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us the exact error message that you're getting please?

Comment: it most cases you will have the app on one server , and the database on another.